# How to get an old SSL1.0 library that is required to run an old program?

Tags: openssl, steam, libcrypto, libssl

I need at least two SSL1.0 libraries to run a game (AoW3) since my system Mageia recently upgraded to SSL1.1 for security reasons. In the Steam folder, there used to be links to /lib, but they are dead, now that my system removed the old libraries. My plan is to retrieve and put those two libraries in the Steam folder, in place of the old links to /lib. Namely, **libssl.so.1.0** and **libcrypto.so.1.0**, that were replaced by their 1.1 upgrades in /lib.

What I've done so far (last time I compiled something in C++, it was like 30 years ago):

- download and unpack OpenSSL 1.0.2.u
- install make and gcc (x86_64)
- in ~/downloads/openssl-1.0.2.u/, run ./config then /bin/make

This created a lot of .o and .c files in that openssl-1.0.2.u folder, but I can't find any .so library as it seems, only I can find libcrypto.a and libssl.a (and .pc) files. What to do with these files?

Also, the game (AoW3) being a 32-bit software, I wonder if using 64-bit versions of make and gcc is correct.